# Convert n-dimensional Cartesian coordinates to n-dimensional polar (hyperspherical) coordinates in R

Tags: r, arrays

I have a data set with values that can be represented in multi-dimensional cartesian space. e.g.:

```
> data = matrix(1:20, ncol = 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

Each row is a data-point, and each column represents a dimension. I would like to study the direction of each data point relative to the origin, rather than their absolute distance to the origin. I would therefore like to convert the data-set into a 4-d polar coordinate space (aka hyperspherical coordinates).

If I only wanted to convert two dimensions, this could be achieved using one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351178/r-converting-cartesian-coordinates-to-polar-coordinates-and-then-calculating-d). Is there a general solution that will allow conversion to n-dimensional polar space? The closest example I have found is the [CoordinateTransformData](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransformData.html) function in the Wolfram language, which generates the symbolic algebra for conversion into n-dimensions.

Comment: Maybe you find something there [Generating multidimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016806/10488504)

Comment: Thanks GKI, unfortunately nothing helpful on that thread, which deals only with Cartesian coordiantes.

Comment: One answer is converting from polar to cartesian. You have to inverse these steps.